# mongodb service not running after changing path

Tags: mongodb

I have changed the dbpath of mongodb.conf.
And after that trying to start mongodb service,when I run

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

I get back

```
mongodb start/running, process 7320
```

After that I run:

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

And getting back

```
mongodb stop/waiting
```

When I want to access mongo shell by :

```
 mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Sun Oct 28 13:01:36 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

But when I start mongod as manually by `mongod --dbpath=/mnt/data/db` it runs fine.
And I can access the mongo shell by `mongo` command.

I have correct permission for my data directory.

Any clue where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem for me. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that [mongodb.conf](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) is not getting loaded because of wrong location (typically this is /etc/mongodb.conf) or a typo when you launch through service start

Try launching manually

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

to rule out any issues with the conf file.

Comment: no issue with conf file,it works fine when I do mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Answer (score 1):

Also check the owner of the old path and compare it to the owner of the new path with `ls -la`. It's possible that you created the new dbpath as a different user than mongodb runs as, so you would need to use `chown` to change the owner.

Answer (score -1):

Check the config file there will be bind-ip and port pass that value while connecting to client

```
mongo <ip.add.re.ss>:<port>/<dbname>
```

assume ip is 10.10.10.2 and port is 27017

```
mongo 10.10.10.2:27017/test
```

Comment: The question is about the configuration file location, not IP address.